tRPC endless loop as a non signed in user
I am using tRPC for my SAAS application. Followed the instructions online and have the following code in place:
Client side under src\app\auth-callback
"use client"

import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import { trpc } from "../_trpc/client";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";

const Page = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const origin = searchParams.get("origin");

    const { data } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
        retry: true,
        retryDelay: 1000
    });

    if (data) {
        if (data.success == true) {
            // user is synced to db
            router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : '/dashboard');
        }
        else if (data.success == false) {
            // user is not synced to db
            router.push('/sign-in');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="w-full mt-24 flex justify-center">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
                <Loader2 className="h-8 w-8 animate-spin text-zinc-800" />
                <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl">
                    Setting up your account...
                </h3>
                <p>You will be redirected automatically</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page

on the server side under src\trpc
import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';
import { publicProcedure, router } from './trpc';
import { db } from '@/db';

export const appRouter = router({
    authCallback: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
        const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession()
        const user = await getUser()
        if (!user.id || !user.email) return { success: false }

        //check if the user is in in the database
        const dbUser = await db.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                id: user.id
            }
        })

        if (!dbUser) {
            // create user in db
            await db.user.create({
                data: {
                    id: user.id,
                    email: user.email
                }
            })
        }

        return { success: true }
    })
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;

If I call http://localhost:3000/auth-callback?origin=dashboard with a signed in user, this code works fine. If there is no signed in user, the application goes into infinite loop calling http://localhost:3000/api/trpc/authCallback?batch=1&input=%7B%7D. Can someone explain why it happens?
I followed https://trpc.io/ instructions for setting trpc, but seems like as a new joiner, there are somethings beyond my knowledge.
